# Mass with vertical spring on a bar

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, spring

[image]

At this exercise, the equation given in the textbook solution is:

$$I\ddot\theta = l_2u-k_1\theta l_1^2-k_2(l_2\theta-y)l_2\qquad (1)$$
$$m_2\ddot y=k_2(l_2\theta-y)\qquad (2)$$

Now, I can't figure out the following terms:

1. $-k_2(l_2\theta-y)l_2$ in equation (1). Why the displacement $y$ is subtracted from $l_2\theta$, shouldn't they add?
2. $k_2(l_2\theta-y)$ in equation (2). Shouldn't the force balance on the block with mass $m_2$ be $(k_2(l_2\theta-y)-m_2g)$?

Comment: This very same question was posed yesterday by the very same OP.

Comment: This question is different, now I want to know where the terms come from. I still can't understand the force balance. Am I doing some crime? I suppose the goal of this website is to clear people's misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first equation, the last term is the clockwise torque exerted on the bar by the stretching of spring 2.  The stretch consists of the arc length lift at the end of the bar minus the lift of the hanging mass.
At equilibrium spring 2 is already stretched enough to support the weight of mass 2 (and spring 1 supports them both plus the bar).  Equation 2 reflects the net force as you move away from equilibrium.

Comment: Sir, I don't understand. The total displacement of the spring should be $y+l\sin(\theta)$, no? If $\theta>0$ then there is $l\theta$ more displacement...

Comment: Note that if θ is positive, the displace at the end of the bar is in the same direction as the indicated y.  The stretch is the difference.